# Class Sheets not found

Tags: php, laravel, google-sheets

Hey guys I have integrated Google sheets using [revolution/laravel-google-sheets](https://packagist.org/packages/revolution/laravel-google-sheets) following this blog https://drivemarketing.ca/en/blog/connecting-laravel-to-a-google-sheet/

Everything works well on my development environment so I have pushed my code to my staging server to test. After pushing my code to the staging server, I ran the following commands `composer update`, `php artisan config:cache` and `composer dump-autoload` in that order. When I test the flow, I get an exception error

> ERROR: Class 'Sheets' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):

Below is a snippet of the controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Sheets;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class MainController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Write user details to google sheet
     * 
     * @param $user
     */
    public function writeUserToSheets($user)
    {
        Sheets::spreadsheet('google sheet id')->sheet('users')
            ->append([
                [$user->id, $user->email, $user->first_name, $user->last_name, $user->created_at->toDateTimeString()]
            ]);
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything? How do I get my code to work on my staging server?

Comment: You need the full namespace of the `Sheets` class. I doubt its in the Controllers\API namespace?

Comment: From the documentation, looks like `use Revolution\Google\Sheets\Sheets;`.

Comment: I gave it a shot but i still get the same error. Keep in mind that I am using the same code and using `Use Sheets;` on both my dev and staging environment.

Comment: Its not being loaded in your current evnironment then - is it installed and added to the autoloader?

Comment: Could you share your composer.json file?

Comment: So I am not sure what happened but after running `composer dump-autoload` & `composer update` a couple of times, the code ran successfully.